# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined react

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help with this? I got the file AddPost.js

```
</div>
                            {this.props.admin.post.PostImage ?
                                <img src={API.makeFileURL(this.props.admin.post.PostImage[0].url, this.props.auth.token)} className="post-image" /> 
                            : null}
                            <div>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained" 
                                    color="primary"
                                    onClick={e => {
                                        $('.MyFile').trigger('click'); 
                                    }}
                                ><ImageIcon />Upload Post Image</Button>
                                <input type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} className="MyFile" onChange={this.uploadImage}/>
                            </div>
```

And API file contains this function:

```
makeFileURL: (url, token) => {
        return host + url + "?access_token" + token;
    }
```

Comment: `this.props.admin.post.PostImage[0]` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Link,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
export const Category = ({match}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to={`${match.url}/mobile`} >Mobile</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={`${match.url}/laptop`} >Laptop</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={`${match.url}/shoes`} >Shoes</Link></li>
            </ul>
           
        </div>
    )
}
```

In this case any one have get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"
so need to change

```
<Route path='/category' component={Category} />
```

Comment: <Route  path='/category' component={category} /> instead of   
          <Route  path='/product' >
            <Category/>
          </Route>

Answer (score 0):

What do `this.props.admin.post` and  `this.props.admin.post.PostImage` evaluate to? I'd start with `console.log`'ing those out and making sure that it returns an array of objects that have a `url` property

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
this.props.admin.post.PostImage&&
this.props.admin.post.PostImage[0]&&
this.props.admin.post.PostImage[0].url
```